# Compactness & Continuity - Looking for feedbacks on a specific setting

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, self-learning, compactness

I am trying to get the implications of the following general setting concerning compact spaces and continuous maps.

*Any feedback would be greatly appreciated, because I have some difficulties in applying what I know from the books, to settings that are outside books.*

Assume that $X, Y$ are compact metric spaces, and that there is a map

$$ \mu :  X \to \Delta (X \times Y)$$

such that $\mu$ is *continuous*, where $\Delta (\Omega)$ denotes the set of probability measures over a generic $\Omega$ . Endow $X \times Y$ with the *product topology*, and $ \Delta (X \times Y)$ with the *topology of weak convergence*.

**Broad Problems:**
*What should I think exactly when I have such a setting?

What conclusions should I infer regarding it?*

---

**Some thoughts &** ***a more specific problem:***

The continuity of $\mu$ tells us that when we have an open (resp. *closed*) subset $G$ of $ \Delta (X \times Y)$, we are ensured that the preimage $\mu^{-1} (G)$ is open (resp. *closed*). But here my intuition is close to failure and I have the following problems.

1. Let $X$ be finite, hence compact. Let $G = \{ \delta_{(x,y)} \}$, where $\delta$ denotes the Dirac measure for some elements $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$. Thus $\mu^{-1} (\{ \delta_{(x,y)} \} )$  maps to some element $ x \in X$. But now, how can $\mu$ really be continuous in this case?
   *Do we actually base the statement on the topological notion of continuity, based in this case on the idea that we are implicitly endowing the finite $X$ with the discrete topology?* **(Problem 1)**
2. Is it correct the fact that a subset of $ \Delta (X \times Y)$ is actually a number? *(it should be the case, but better to be sure...)* **(Problem 2)**
3. Is it better to see at Problem 1 as I stated, but focusing on *closed* sets, rather than open. Indeed, we are allowed, because in the discrete topology, subsets are *clopen*, and a specific number attached to $\mu$ should be closed in the topology of weak convergence, e.g.  $G = 1/2$.
   *Is this a correct line of reasoning?* **(Problem 3)**