# Compactness, continuity and the discrete topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, self-learning

Assume that $X, Y$ are compact metric spaces, and that there is a map

$$ \mu :  X \to \Delta (X \times Y)$$

such that $\mu$ is *continuous*, where $\Delta (\Omega)$ denotes the set of probability measures over a generic $\Omega$ . Endow $X \times Y$ with the *product topology*, and $ \Delta (X \times Y)$ with the *topology of weak convergence*.

The continuity of $\mu$ tells us that when we have an open (resp. *closed*) subset $G$ of $ \Delta (X \times Y)$, we are ensured that the preimage $\mu^{-1} (G)$ is open (resp. *closed*). However, I have a problem with the following situation.

Let $X$ be finite, hence compact. Let $G = \{ \delta_{(x,y)} \}$, where $\delta$ denotes the Dirac measure for some elements $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$. Thus $\mu^{-1} (\{ \delta_{(x,y)} \} )$  maps to some element $ x \in X$. But now, how can $\mu$ really be continuous in this case?

*Is it continuous because we are implicitly endowing the finite $X$ with the discrete topology?*

Any feedback or answer is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

---

*PS: To the moderators, this questions looks fairly close to this [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195426/compactness-continuity-looking-for-feedbacks-on-a-specific-setting). However, they are different in spirit, because that question is not well written (too many questions into one). Hence, I decided to "unzip" it, starting from this one. Regarding this issue, I think it would be wise to close that linked question (I don't know how to do it).*

Comment: What do you mean by $G$? For $\mu^{-1}(\{1/2\})$ to be well-defined, you would need that $\{1/2\}$ is a **subset** of $\Delta(X\times Y)$, which does not seem to be the case, at least not without making some identifications.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I changed in a way that hopefully makes sense (I was not sure if I should have written $\{ \delta_{(x,y)} \}$ or $\{ (\delta_x, \delta_y) \}$ – ...but the two should be the same, right?)

Comment: Finite metric space always has discrete topology, no?

Comment: Treu, but I am simply assuming $X$ to be finite. Does it actually implies that every topology on a finite space is necessarily metrizable, and hence discrete (and Hausdorff)?

Comment: How do you define weak convergence?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: I guess in the standard way, i.e. let $X$ be a metric space,  then a sequence $\mu_n$ converges *weakly* to $\mu$ iff  $\int f d \mu_n \to \int f d \mu$, for every continuous linear functional $f$ on $X$. Or, by properly translating the entire setting in TVS terms, I see weak convergence as the same as the weak-* topology on the dual pair $\langle C_b (X) , \Delta (X) \rangle $.

Comment: @Kolmin Are you sure you want $f$ to be linear?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Quite frankly, (narrow-mindedly) I did not conceive another option. Btw, I think I will start a (conspicuous... relative to my points) bounty in few minutes. Thus, if you would like to answer and add whatever fancy you regarding this topic, it would be really a pleasure, and I am sure I would learn a lot. :)

Comment: 1. Just let $f$ be continuous and bounded. 2. Even with non-Hausdorff topologies on a finite set, the resulting $\sigma$-algebra has a very simple form. Let $x\equiv y$ if $x$ and $y$ are members of exactly the same open sets. If $M$ is finit or even countably infinite, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra will consists of all arbitrary unions of $\equiv$-equivalence classes. This equivalence classes are like points. If you quotient out, you can pretend to be working in a discrete setting.

Comment: Where your $M$ is my $X$. And thus, out of this pretending, we can say that $\mu$ is indeed continuous, right?

Comment: $\mu^{-1} (\{ \delta_{(x,y)} \} )$ is not necessary one point, it could easily be the whole $X$ or the empty set, or any closed set for that matter. Topology should not necessary be discrete, though as Michael Greinecker noticed, it comes down to the discrete one from the topological point of view.

Comment: @Jorkug: But, correct me if I am wrong, $\mu^{-1} ( \{ \delta_{(x,y)} \} )$ has to map to something (it cannot be empty), otherwise the continuity of $\mu$ we are assuming should not work, right?

Comment: Why not, the empty set is both open and closed, so $\mu^{-1}(G)$ being empty doesn't contradict anything. In fact, take $\mu(x)\equiv \delta_{(x_0,y_0)}$, then the preimage of anything that doesn't contain $\delta_{(x_0,y_0)}$ is empty, the constant map being naturally continuous in *any* topology on $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant map between two space is always continuous, in ANY topology you consider.

Suppose  $\mu$ is constant, that is to say $\mu(x_1)=\mu(x_2)$ for any $x_1,x_2\in X$ and suppose $\mu(x)$ is not a dirac delta.

Then $\mu^{-1}(\delta_{(x,y)})$ is just empty, so it is not an element of $X$.

This is not a particular case because if $X$ is finite, say with $n$ elements, then the image of $\mu$ consists of just $n$ measures, and the space of probability measures on $X\times Y$ contains infinitely many elements provided $n\geq 2$ and $Y\neq\emptyset$.

Finally, if you endow $X$ with the discrete topology, then ANY map from $X$ to ANY topological space is continuous. On the other opposite, if $X$ has the trivial topology (the open sets are $X$ and $\emptyset$) then a function from $X$  to a $T_0$ space is continuous if and only if it is constant. Between these two cases you have intermediate cases.

Example. Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ with topology given by $\tau=\{X,\emptyset, \{a\}, \{b,c\}\}$ then a function from $X$ to a $T_0$ space is continuous if and only if $f(b)=f(c)$.

Comment: First of all, thank you for you answer. In second place, could you summarize in one statement your answer to question in italics?

Comment: the answer to the question in italic is: No, you can have continuous functions $\mu:X\to\Delta(X\times Y)$ independently on the topology you put on $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and the comment. Regarding the fact that you mention the constant map as the one that ALWAYS make the job, if we don't think about that map, then things get less smooth, and you have to check the topology to see if something is continuous or not, right?

Comment: The fact is that you have not many topologies on a finite set. If the topology is $T_0$ then it is discrete. Otherwise, given two points that are not distinguishable, any continuous function with image in a $T_0$ space has the same value on them. Thus you can quotient $X$ identifying such points. The results is a finite set with the discrete topology. So basically if your target is $T_0$ then you always reduce the case of finite spaces to that of finite discrete spaces.